# Oracle - Split record into multiple record based on column value

Tags: oracle

How can I achieve below result in Oracle, table name - EMP_REC. If SPLIT field = 'YES', it should split AMOUNT into 2 records (50% of original value).

```
CURRENT DATASET
---------------
ID      AMT          SPLIT
----------------------------
111      500        'YES'
222      500         'NO'


REQUIRED RESULT
---------------
ID   AMT    SPLIT
---------------------------
111      250        'YES'
111      250        'YES'
222      500        'NO'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the result you are after (pretty straightforward one):

```
with yes_perc(yes, prc) as (
  select 'YES'
       , count(1) over() as prc
    from dual
  connect by level <= 2
)
select t.id
     , case 
         when t.split1 = y.yes
         then t.amt / y.prc
         else t.amt
       end as amt
     , t.split1
  from your_table_name t
       left join yes_perc y
         on (t.split1 = y.yes)
```

Result:

```
        ID        AMT   SPLIT1
---------- ----------   ------
       111        250   YES    
       111        250   YES    
       222        500   NO
```